# PHP IF-ELSE STAMENT

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators

Code:

```
<?php
$a = 200;
$b = 300;
if ($a > $b + $b != 3)
    print "Correct";

else
print "Incorrect";
?>
```

output is: **Correct**

Can someone help me understand why the output became "Correct"?

Comment: `if ($a > $b && $b != 3)`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php - Your if statement becomes `(($a > ($b + $b)) != 3)`

Comment: `if (200 > 300 + 300 != 3)`

Comment: I can't think of a way of putting brackets around that statement that would ever be useful - are you just throwing symbols at PHP to see what happens? I'm not saying that's a bad thing if you're learning, but it's a lot harder to give you constructive advice for random experiments than it is to help with an actual problem.

Comment: While this teaches the precedence of operators, it is also very unwise to write code like that. The reader needs to put extra effort into understanding this because he needs to remember that precedence. Either use parentheses or put `$b + $b` in another variable.

Comment: Perhaps you intend `+` to stand for "and"? In that case it would be: `($a > $b && $b != 3)`

Answer (score 3):

To understand what is happening here, you need to look at the list of [operator precendence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) to see what is being evaluated first. It's not left to right. The order of the operators in your if statement are as follows:

1. `+ - ++ -- ~ (int) (float) (string) (array) (object) (bool) @`  - arithmetic (unary + and -), increment/decrement, bitwise, type casting and error control
2. `< <= > >=` - associative comparison
3. `== != === !== <> <=>` - non associative comparison

So in essence, your if statement breaks down to this:

```
(($a > ($b + $b)) != 3)
```

With your values becomes

```
((200 > (300 + 300)) != 3)
((200 > 600) != 3)
(false != 3)
```

So of course, false is not 3, and makes your if statement correct.  If you want to evaluation `200 is greater than 300 AND 300 is not 3`, then you need the logical AND operator, or `&&`, which would be

```
($a > $b && $b != 3)
```

which would print `Incorrect`